# why i am getting the uncaught type error:can't find property of undefined

Tags: javascript

This is the first time I am working with JavaScript modules. I am trying to upload an image and show it in a `div` under `'id="imageholder"'`.

The error is:

> uncaught type error :can't find property 'fileread' of undefined

HTML:

```
<html>

<body>
  <div id='imageholder' style='width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black;position:relative;left:100px;'></div>
  <input type='file' id='up' />
  <script src='myscript.js'></script>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('change', FileUpload.files, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the **myscript.js** module file which should return the object called **FileUpload**. But error is saying it is `undefined`. Why it is 
`undefined`? It is long but it works when I don't use it like a module but all in a single file.

You can jump at the end and can see I am returning an object literal to `FileUpload` variable.

```
var FileUpload = (function(fileElement) {

  var imageholder = document.getElementById('imageholder');

  function getBLOBFileHeader(url, blob, callback, callbackTwo) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadend = function(e) {
      var arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result)).subarray(0, 4);
      var header = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        header += arr[i].toString(16);
      }
      console.log(header);
      var imgtype = callback(url, header); // headerCallback

      callbackTwo(imgtype, blob)
    };

    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  }

  function headerCallback(url, headerString) {

    var info = getHeaderInfo(url, headerString);
    return info;
  }

  function getTheJobDone(mimetype, blob) {

    var mimearray = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'];

    if (mimearray.indexOf(mimetype) != -1) {
      printImage(blob);
    } else {
      fileElement.value = '';
      while (imageholder.firstChild) {
        imageholder.removeChild(imageholder.firstChild);
      }
      // alert('you can not upload this file type');
    }
  }

  function remoteCallback(url, blob) {
    getBLOBFileHeader(url, blob, headerCallback, getTheJobDone);
  }

  function printImage(blob) {
    // Add this image to the document body for proof of GET success
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onloadend = function(e) {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
      img.setAttribute('style', 'width:100%;height:100%;');
      imageholder.appendChild(img);
    };

    fr.readAsDataURL(blob);
  }

  function mimeType(headerString) {

    switch (headerString) {

      case "89504e47":
        type = "image/png";
        break;
      case "47494638":
        type = "image/gif";
        break;
      case "ffd8ffe0":
      case "ffd8ffe1":
      case "ffd8ffe2":
        type = "image/jpeg";
        break;
      default:
        type = "image/pjpeg";
        break;
    }

    return type;
  }

  function getHeaderInfo(url, headerString) {
    return (mimeType(headerString));
  }

  // Check for FileReader support
  function fileread(event) {

    if (window.FileReader && window.Blob) {


      /* Handle local files */
      var mimetype;
      var mimearray = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'];

      var file = event.target.files[0];

      if (mimearray.indexOf(file.type) === -1 || file.size >= 2 * 1024 * 1024) {
        while (imageholder.firstChild) {
          imageholder.removeChild(imageholder.firstChild);
        }
        fileElement.value = '';

        file = null;
        return false;

      } else {

        while (imageholder.firstChild) {
          imageholder.removeChild(imageholder.firstChild);
        }
        remoteCallback(file.name, file);
      }
    } else {
      // File and Blob are not supported
      console.log('file and blob is not supported');
    }
  }
  return {
    files: fileread
  };
}(document.getElementById('up')))
```

Comment: Do you know which line is causing the error?

Comment: Fairly certain the parens in the last line are not correct.  Try this: `})(document.getElementById('up'))`

Comment: Your code works for me. https://plnkr.co/edit/HTTTsLTzar54pdHbr91j?p=preview

Comment: I'm also not able to duplicate the problem. I'm going to guess that the script is not loading as I did see a similar error under that condition. Have you verified that your "myscript.js" is actually loaded?

Comment: @mparnisari then why it is not working for me..?

Comment: Are you referencing the file correctly?

Comment: yes i am..they are all in the same directory

Comment: In the dev console, under the network tab, do you see the script loading without errors?

Comment: in my console i see the error which is in the title of the question.It is not finding the property of an undefined object.I ckecked by keeping all in the single file .but sitlls the same.As you can see it works ,but not in my browser both in chrome and firefox.I don't know what to do.

Comment: What do you see with `console.log(FileUpload);`? Do you know the line number of the error? I don't even see a reference to a property named `fileread`.

Comment: console.log(FIleUpload) returns undefined.error line is 159 according to  chrome console. i mean in the      document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('change', FileUpload.files, false);

Comment: Nobody can duplicate the error. So you'll need to provide a jsfiddle or some other runnable code sample that demonstrates the error.

Answer (score 1):

it's working right as you provided it **jsfiddle.net/fredo5n8/** here is the proof.

Are you sure you did not forget to wipe cache in your browser? If that's the case, try to run the code in incognito (private) window.

### **EDIT:**

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id='imageholder' style='width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black;position:relative;left:100px;'></div>
  <input type='file' id='up' />
  <script id='myscript' src='myscript.js'></script>
  <script>
 var script = document.getElementById('myscript');
 var attachInputEvents = function () {
        document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('change', FileUpload.files, false);
 }
 script.onload=attachInputEvents();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This way, you'll wait for the srcript to load(I guess that's the problem, cause locally on my machine even with separate files, it worked good hosted on WAMP server)

Comment: Note that OP says "it works when I don't use it like a module but all in a single file" ... and the fiddle appears to be a single file.

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay enough attention. But I also tried it locally with separate files, and it's still working. I guess he should just add **onload** event on the script tag, and then add the change event listener on the input element

Comment: i did what you suggest but still getting the error.I don't know what to do.Could it be a problem with the browsers..

Comment: @AL-zami it wouldn't work in the snippet, there's no script file, only the html. The provided html didn't work on your local machine?

Comment: no it didn't work..i can see from others snippet that code works fine.From your fiddle too.But why it should not work in my browser?

Comment: Which browser and version do you have? Did you try in different browser?

Comment: i used firefox 45 and chrome 49

Comment: I used same versions, same browsers, also tried in Edge and IE11, works there too. Sorry, but I'm out of ideas what may be causing your problem. Your code is good.